# How to deploy GUI on an existing complicated program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

First of all, sorry for the little broad question. Just want to get some general idea of direction.

Right now I have a big project almost completed. It has over 5 classes and under complicated designs and initially non-GUI, and I want to add a GUI interface to it. the GUI was supposed to fetch information when it runs and displays the running information. I reads about Swings and SwingWorker but it seems not plausible to put entire original program under Background thread. Right now I'm think putting GUI as a separated class but I don't know what's the best way to make connections. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a "frontend"? It is a GUI that does not integrate with the original program, but simply launches it as a separate process and reads its output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply "put" a GUI on any existing program, but you can possibly give a program a GUI user interface ***if*** the program was well constructed in a very modular fashion such that its UI is well separated from its logic code, for example if it was constructed in an M-V-C (model-view-control) fasion.

As always, the devil is in the details, none of which I can discuss at the moment given the limited information that we possess about your current project and needs. If you need further help, you will need to give us more information and code.